# Latest Tweet From User That Includes Hashtag

Tags: php, twitter, hashtag

I have the following code that'll show the latest tweet from a user on my page.

```
<div id="last-tweet" class="grid_12">
<p><b>@user: </b> <?php
$username='username'; // set user name
$format='json'; // set format
$tweet=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/{$username}.{$format}")); // get tweets and decode them into a variable
echo $tweet[0]->text; // show latest tweet
?></p>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how I can add a 'hashtag' constraint to this so it would only show tweets from this user with a particular hashtag?

Thanks
dvent

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use Twitter's search api. Once you fetched the result, simply use the first tweet and ignore the others.

**Example:**
Hashtag #nowplaying in tweets from user @MusicMagic_TBS (random example which I found with a quick Twitter search)

**Twitter API v1.1:** 
Query: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23nowplaying%20from:MusicMagic_TBS
Doc: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets

**Twitter API v1.0 (deprecated):**
Query: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23nowplaying%20from:MusicMagic_TBS
Doc: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search

Answer (score 0):

You can add hashtag constraints and check for hashtags using [Tweet Entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/entities)

See this question and answer for more context: [Is there any way to get links, hashtags, and @names from Twitter API requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587730/is-there-any-way-to-get-links-hashtags-and-names-from-twitter-api-requests/11597887#11597887)

The `latest` tweet with a hashtag can be found by filtering out the responses to only ones that include the hashtags and looking at the top of the response stack.

Comment: Hi Chamilyan - I can see that this looks like what I need, but I'm not experienced enough to know how to amend my code above to reflect this. Can you please help me get a few steps closer?

Comment: did you have any luck fixing this? I can guide you to the console where you can test the Twitter calls i'm describing. https://dev.twitter.com/console